# ASP.NET mvc3 Custom resource provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, translation

I am having some trouble with mvc3 and a custom resource provider. I created a custom resource provider with a database.

I added the settings in my web.config.

But how can I get localized strings in my views with the resourceprovider ?

I can't find info anywhere.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 I have been using this syntax in view:

```
@ViewContext.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("Glossary", "Hello")
```

Hand in hand together with resource provider model. There I have a factory which returns current source (file, relation database or Entity Framework ORM).